# Can you give an object a key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If you have an array of objects like

```
[{rID:53, name:Roger, age:43},{rID:12, name:Phil, age:22}]
```

is it possible instead to give each a object a key like

```
 [53:{name:Roger, age:43},12:{name:Phil, age:22}]
```

?

I understand that each object has an index number, but I'm looking for a way to find objects not based on their index pos, and preferably without having to loop through until you find an object with rID=53 type thing.

I'd be using PKs from mysql rows to give each object it's key.

Cheers

Comment: No it's not, arrays don't have named keys. you could of course use an object instead of the array.

Comment: @Shaun An object is an associative array.

Comment: Thanks Adeneo - how do you mean mate? Don't I need an array if I'm dealing with a bunch of objects?

Comment: Yes it is possible. `var arr = []; arr[12] = yourObject`. But I wouldn't advise it. It causes confusion during looping - use an object instead. `var obj = {}; obj['12'] = yourObject`;

Answer (score 2):

If you want an unordered collection of variables with arbitrary keys. Then use an object.

```
{"53":{name:Roger, age:43},"12":{name:Phil, age:22}}
```

Arrays can have only numeric keys, but if you want to assign a value to an arbitrary position, you have to do so after creating the array.

```
var some_array = [];
some_array[53] = {name:Roger, age:43};
some_array[22] = {name:Phil, age:22};
```

Note that this will set the array length to 54.

Note that in both cases, you can't have multiple values for a given property (although you could have an array of values there).

Comment: +1 for explaining the this can be accomplished with arrays, but probably shouldn't be.

Comment: A property name does not need to be a string. Numeric literals do work as well (unless you have JSON).

Comment: this is very bad for looping

Answer (score 2):

You need an object for that.

```
{
  53: {
    name: "Roger",
    age: 43
  },
  12: {
    name: "Phil",
    age: 22
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's only numeric indicies, then you can use an array, as the OP suggested. But I would advise to use an object instead.

Comment: The quotes are not necessary, unless you've got JSON. And WTH is that "quick hack" good for?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot have a *key* and an *index* in a js array. Arrays only have indices, Objects only have keys. There is no such thing like a associative array in JavaScript. If the order (of your original array) does not matter, you can use an object though:

```
{53:{name:"Roger", age:43},12:{name:"Phil", age:22}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use objects to do this

```
var map = {"53":{"name": "Roger", "age": "43"},"12":{"name": "Phil", "age": "22"}};
```

Then access the value like an array (note, i'm using string because that's what keys are stored as, strings, you can access it using an integer, but it will just be converted to a string when searching for the property anyway):

```
map["53"]
```

You can also loop through this map object:

```
for (var key in map) {
   var value = map[key];
}
```

Comment: OK - I think this is what I'm after. I'm looking for a way that allows me to target a particular object without looping, yet still be able to loop through to display data from all the objects.Thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for your help here. I had no idea you could set up an object like this - "53":{"name": "Roger", "age": "43"}, and it's just make finding and deleting keys SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO much easier than looping through an array to find what I need to delete. Cheers!

Comment: Quick question - what if you need to rely on the order being preserved when you're looping?

Comment: Object properties are not guaranteed to be ordered, only arrays are. Both have different functions, since ordering and searching are not exactly the same thing. Anyway unless you're dealing with tens of thousands of records and/or sorting it really often; sorting your objects based on key and then putting them into an array is quick. Or if you don't mind duplicate data, you can have an array for looping and object for quick access by key, you'll need to manually add/remove data to both variables though.

Comment: Thanks Populus - that's made me rethink my attack plan.